# What color feature is important for white-like tones?

Tags: image-processing, svm, image-segmentation, feature-extraction

I am building an image segmentation model using SVM as a pixel-wise classifier. I am segmentating pressure ulcers. They have different kind of tissues inside. I want to get the region of the ulcer. I have features like RGB intensities, red, green and blue chromatocities. A type of tissue inside the ulcer has white like colors, but most of the ulcer is reddish. I am getting correct results for the reddish colors but not the whites. 
Can anyone point me a feature or set of features that can captures white textures or white color information to include in the feature vector? 
Thanks in advance...

Comment: Can't you just normalize your rgb value to a unit vector and then measure angle between that vector and the unit vector towards 1,1,1?

Comment: @SneakyPolarBear, I have my RGB normalized as feature as well, but what does finding the angle beween the unit vector will yield? intensity invariant?

Comment: Yes, as far as I know, that should give you the strongest, intensity invariant "white-ness" classifier.

Comment: @SneakyPolarBear, oh. Will try that. But ultimately I noticed that my dataset have an issue. The problem is that the pictures were not taken in a controlled environment, thus there are things not related to skin or pressure ulcer itself like white tiles, walls and other white things and I think that is confusing my classifier because there are white colors very much alike on the training set classified as ulcer and others are not.. Am I right about this? This may be an issue right? So I think I should find a better dataset. What do you think?

Comment: That depends, so long as you train the white *with surrounding tissues* it should be specific against stuff like walls.  But easier still may be to pre-process the images to remove all "non-human flesh" from the image, like an edge detection or the like so that you don't need as sophisticated of a clasifier that can ignore background disturbances.

Comment: @SneakyPolarBear, thanks for the suggestion about removing non human flesh from the image. Will try that approach out and get back here to let you know.